# DetourFunction is undefined

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using this code for hooking and I am using MS Detours. I have placed Detours.cpp, Detours.h, Detours.lib into **detours** directory Which I temporarily created into hooking folder Where my VS (Visual Studio) code lies. I used VS settings to include the placed detours directory as the directory of "Additional include directory" and "Additional Library directory" . 
The program is here

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "detours.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

typedef BOOL (__stdcall* tGetFileVersionInfoExW)(DWORD dwFlags, LPCWSTR lpwstrFilename, DWORD dwHandle, DWORD dwLen, LPVOID lpData);
tGetFileVersionInfoExW pGetFileVersionInfoExW;

BOOL WINAPI MyGetFileVersionInfoExW(DWORD dwFlags, LPCWSTR lpwstrFilename, DWORD dwHandle, DWORD dwLen, LPVOID lpData)
{
    //Messagebox
    MessageBox(NULL, "myGetFileVersionInfoExW Just Got Called","InsertDateTime", MB_OK);
    return pGetFileVersionInfoExW(dwFlags, lpwstrFilename, dwHandle, dwLen, lpData); //Return the origional function
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) //Decide what to do
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: //On dll attach
        {
            pGetFileVersionInfoExW = (tGetFileVersionInfoExW)DetourFunction((PBYTE)0x0100A036, (PBYTE)MyGetFileVersionInfoExW);
        }
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: //On thread attach
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH: //On thread detach
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: //on process detach
        {
            DetourRemove((PBYTE)pGetFileVersionInfoExW, (PBYTE)MyGetFileVersionInfoExW);
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Still I am getting this error-

```
IntelliSense: identifier "DetourRemove" is undefined    
IntelliSense: identifier "DetourFunction" is undefined
```

If I am using the default installation directory if MS Detours, the program still do not compile. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Old version is `DetourFunction` and `DetourRemove`, now the name was changed to `DetourAttach` and `DetourDetach` (Detours ver. 2.0 or above).